# How to use Kendo UI within a stand-alone orchard module?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, kendo-ui

I'm writing a custom modulo to present the user with a grid to allow the end-user to see and manage "non-content-part" data. This data is data feed to the database from an outside source. The module, for simplicity, register a route for the mysite/Manager path as bellow:

```
public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes() {
    return new[] {
        new RouteDescriptor {
            Priority = 5,
            Route = new Route(
                "Manager/{controller}/{action}",
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                    {"area", "XpiManager"},
                    {"controller", "Home"},
                    {"action", "Index"}
                },
                new RouteValueDictionary(),
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                    {"area", "XpiManager"}
                },
                new MvcRouteHandler())
        }
    };
```

As we can see it is just as if its a stand-alone app inside the Orchard.

This is the very simple code for the Home controller:

```
[Themed]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("XpiManager");
    }
}
```

It uses the `ThemedAttribute` so that the end-user feels as if he is still inside the side and not in a kind of sub application...

Since I need some nice end-user capabilities added to the grid, and since I've got a full subscription for Telerik's controls, including the full KendoUI package I want to use their server-side wrappers to create this grid in my template code, which currently has the following place-holder code:

```
<h1>Site's Manager</h1>
```

Yes, just that... I want to be able to do something like this in this template:

```
@model IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock);
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
    )
)
```

As a last resort, I could use the client-side only Kendo UI with javascript, but that would make it a lot harder for me to bind to my datasource. I'm pretty newbie in both Kendo UI and Orchard (although I'm a little more experienced in the latter...)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to the Kendo UI server-side components in the theme project and use the helpers from there. I've done the same thing and it works like a charm.

If you can't add the reference, because you're not running from the source version, here's another technique that could work. Add an entry to the `<namespaces>` in the razor section in your web.config file for the Kendo UI stuff.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="...">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="..." />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Make sure that you also add references to the required assemblies in the web.config files, otherwise the website will not run properly.

```
<compilation debug="..." targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="..."/>

  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

That's all there is to it. The rest is a matter of getting the records from the database using `IRepository<T>` and calling the right methods on the Kendo UI component helpers.

Comment: (I've replied before on the wrong place, if you see a strange comment you can't read - I've deleted it - don't think you're going crazy, it is just me!)

In my case I was using it in a custom module, not on a theme. It makes no sense to force a change on a theme for the benefit of a module... But I think that I could do the same thing you did, only in the module's, and it would work. I would have to revisit that project and change it. But since I resolved it by using only the client-side Kendo UI, without the helpers, and the project is long delivered, I don't know when I'll check it out!